# Add custom icon on marker mapbox.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, leaflet.draw

Below is my draw marker code in which I want to add custom icon.

```
  drawMarker: function() {
    this.drawnItems.clearLayers();
    this.drawHandler = new L.Draw.Marker(this.map,this.drawControl.options.draw.marker);
    L.Draw.Marker.options.icon ="/assets/image/marker.png";
    this.drawHandler.enable();
},
```

But custom icon code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I have just replaced below line

```
  this.drawHandler = new L.Draw.Marker(this.map, {icon:L.icon({iconUrl:'/assets/image/marker.png'})});
```

And it worked.